# Facebook LIKE button meta tags produce unwanted result

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have implemented LIKE button on my test page, I used all the og tags to say what it is all about

and the result on my profile page looks like :

Moshe likes title title on website

I don't want the "on website" part because it links back to the root of the server which is not related to me or my content.

I found no way to make the "on website" part disappear and I am sure I am not the first to come across something like that

any ideas ?

thank you..

my og meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title title"/>

<meta property="og:type" content="company"/>

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ppp.com/user394/index.asp"/>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="website"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is a configuration settings on your app on Facebook. You need to set your Site URL to the root path of your website. For example http://www.ppp.com/user394/. This should solve the problem. Here is the link to your apps: http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

Comment: Hi,I heard this before, but could not find an app in my facebook developer apps.

Comment: this is probably because I never created an app, this is just meta tags on a web page... as instructed by the open graph protocol

Comment: now, I created an application, added fb:app_id meta tag and edited the site url in the app settings, nothing changed...plus, the domain can only be the root (e.g. ppp.com), nothing else..

Comment: Did you set the Site Domain property or the Site Url property? The site url is what I was suggesting. That property can have path info in it.

Comment: yes I did, but then I had to add fb:app_id tag to the html. once I did, facebook linter repoted an error until I added site domain